# Tomcat 8 HttpJAASRealm

Tags: java, http, tomcat

After i upgraded my tomcat, from tomcat 6 to tomcat 8, I have an issue after i up the tomcat, Class not found org.apache.catalina.realm.HttpJAASRealm.

className="org.apache.catalina.realm.HttpJAASRealm"

Below the error from Catalina log

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.realm.HttpJAASRealm
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1180)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1448)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: have you specified org.apache.catalina.realm.HttpJAASRealm in your server.xml? I think this should just be org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm. Documentation here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/JAASRealm.html

Comment: Thank you, org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm works

Comment: No problem glad it did :)